# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset - Exception while trying to consume https restful api in java8

Tags: java, rest, java-8

Trying to access https service using below client which has certificates.
This work fine with Java7 when used in Java8 its throwing socket connection exception.
Should any other certificates need to be added ?

```
protected Client getClient() {
    if (client == null) {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustCertificates = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }
                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

            } };
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(SSL);
            sslContext.init(null, trustCertificates, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            final HostnameVerifier verifiedHosts = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
            ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
            config.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
            config.register(Log4j2JerseyLoggingFilter.class);
            return clientBuilder.sslContext(sslContext).hostnameVerifier(verifiedHosts).withConfig(config).build();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            LOG.error("Client Builder Exception " + e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Getting socket connection exception.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1281)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1256)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:385)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 doesn't use TLSv1.2 by default but [Java 8 does](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-8-will-use-tls-12-as-default). The fact it worked in Java 7 points to the server not supporting TLSv1.2. Perhaps you need to change to whatever the server requires, along the lines of:

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
```

Comment: Getting same exception even after changing the protocol in SSLContext